# Copy Firebird fdb from old.fdb to new.fdb with slightly different structure

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to copy a database from old.fdb to new.fdb which has a slightly different structure like additional tables or columns. So, far I've tried using IBPump but it doesn't support FDB it's for GDB.

I tried using FBCopy but it gives me an error

```
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Statement::Prepare( INSERT INTO TABLE1 ("FIELD1","FIELD2","FIELD3") 
VALUES (?,?,?) )
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed

SQL Message : -104
Invalid token
```

Which I think is because my database dialect is 1. Also, I tried using dbMigration .NET but the connection isn't being established because the charset of the database is NONE.

I don't know what to do next. I will really appreciate any help or suggestions.

Comment: is that the actual Insert statement? What are the data types of the fields, are both DBs the same dialect? If that isn't the actual insert statement, can you post the DDL for the tables?

Comment: `IBPump` is a tool using interbase server. It does "supports" neither GDB nor FDB files, it only supports Interbase server and perhaps Firebird subset which imitates Interbase 6. Those are servers that do or do not support files. That being said, i think that IBPump was not updated in looong time, or am i wrong? // w.r.t. FBCopy, which commands did you input into it, according to the manual http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/fbcopy-manual.html ?

Comment: I recommend that you ask this question on the [firebird-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support)